# Email + data server for a small company needed?

Tags: windows-server-2003, security

I am currently working with a small company (10 people), whose main business has nothing to do with IT.

But we have some IT-Infrastructure, namely an aging Small Business 2003 server, which runs Exchange, shared folders and the backup software.

Due to the age, a complete replacement is scheduled for this year and our external IT-support has pitched a configuration which basically consists of two servers: one running exchange, one running our file system / active directory.

I am little wary that they want to sell us something which is too big for our needs so I would like to know if this configuration has some sort of security advantage?

Performance is not of importance, even the old one could handle our few emails and file activity with ease.

Comment: If you wanted to have a little fun you could buy a Raspberry Pi and set up Citadel Suite on it :) Not only is it cheap upfront, it's cheap to run.

Comment: **Did you ask *them*** why they are suggesting splitting the workload across two servers? What was their answer? Remember, you (the company) is their customer -- you can certainly say "no, we don't want to run two machines for this".

Answer (score 1):

Check Office365 for someone online, possibly adding a smaller NAS for a local file storage - depending on your needs.

Exchange at this size is best hosted online.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you know if it's hard to migrate locally stored data to exchange online?
Unfortunately, I can see this option rejected due to legal constraints (working with sensitive data, where concerns about online storage a rampant (living in germany))

Comment: No. Because i do not use them. And there are local german hosters offering hosted exchange - that is quite a run the mill offer in the last years.

Comment: Migrating from on-premises Exchange 2003 to Exchange Online / Office 365 is relatively easy and straightforward.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2013/05/31/step-by-step-migration-of-exchange-2003-server-to-office-365.aspx

Comment: I would not suggest the use of a third-party-cloud-storage when it comes to sensitive data.

Comment: @Broco - without an analysis of the security of the internally-hosted systems, that's a very broad and sometimes incorrect suggestion.

Comment: @mfinni when it comes to cloud services provided by Microsoft this is the right suggestion proven by FACTS. In fact, that is the case for any cloud service hosted in a country not complying with the local laws regarding data-security.

Comment: <citation needed>

Comment: @mfinni This is not a place of a discussion but if you missed the recent NSA-scandal involving many US-companies you have not been paying attention. Citation? Here you go: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/06/19/microsoft_nsa_fallout/ http://www.nytimes.com/2014/05/21/business/us-snooping-on-companies-cited-by-china.html?_r=0

Comment: That has absolutely nothing to do with hosted data - the NSA can get to the stuff that's in your home or office, if you're targeted.

Comment: But the NSA collects unprotected data even if you are NOT targeted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not starting a debate here for Microsoft vs Linux but most of my smaller customers now use Zimbra as Groupware and Samba as PDC. I don't think you really need an Active Directory for 10 users but I did set up a Samba 4 server with AD, roaming profiles and folder redirection for a customer with 3 employees last week. Spared them the costs of the Windows server but still having most of the functions.

Your IT-support suggested to split mail and file server which is ok but the smart thing to do would be to set up 2 VMs (1 for file server, 1 for mail) and have them running on a 2-server-cluster that means if 1 server dies, NONE of your services will stop working and you are still operational until the nonfunctional server is replaced. However, this setup is quite expensive if you run it on Windows.

If you don't want to have a complicated setup like this I would suggest just to use 1 server because the way your IT-support suggested, you would still not be able to work if a server fails, losing either the mail server or the file server temporarily. So you have to deliberate about whether to spend more money on hardware and reducing the risk of not being operational or saving money on hardware. If you can afford to be offline for 1-3 days you won't need high availability (meaning 2 servers), if you can't, you need it.

As you said, you lived in Germany (so do I), you should know about the recent scandals about security concerning Microsoft and cloud-services, so I won't suggest the use of Cloud services provided by this company (that means Office 365).

Working with sensitive data, you should be **very** careful about cloud services, especially those hosted or owned in another nation. Make sure you understand the trade-off you are making if you do decide to use a cloud service, especially one where the company providing it has to answer to a different set of laws than you do.

Comment: This setup is quite expensive whether you run it on Windows or not...

Comment: The hardware pricing when using free software is the same as with the suggested setup, but with Windows the costs would be significantly higher. The suggested setup by the IT-support would produce double the cost of a single server by providing just a little bit more security because not both services are fail safe.

Comment: Surely to cluster you need shared storage, which is not cheap?  Also, which is the free software that supports a hypervisor cluster?

Comment: https://alteeve.ca/w/AN!Cluster_Tutorial_2

Comment: That describes a platform built on RHEL, which is a commercial product.  It's no different to using Hyper-V in that respect.  It's not free.

Comment: I don't have to explain that you can do the same or similar on other Linux distribution or do I?

Answer (score 0):

The division in two machines might be for system stability reasons. If one faults, you can still use the other one. Your business will not totally get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Another option not yet mentioned is Google Apps for Business (Gmail and Google Drive).  It's cheap, but whether G-Drive will work for you depends on a number of factors such as bandwidth, data size and data volatility.